# Applying Linq Expression to IQueryable OrderBy

Tags: linq

Linq2Rest generates SortDescriptions with KeySelectors of type `Expressions<Func<T, U>>`

Assuming I have an `IQueryable<MyObject>`. A KeySelector can be applied to IQueryable.OrderBy as follows:

```cs
var keySelector = SortDescription.KeySelector;
if(keySelector.Type.Equals(typeof(Func<MyObject, Int64>)
{
    queryable = querable.OrderBy<MyObject, Int64>(
        keySelector as Expression<<Func<MyObject, Int64>>);
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically match the Type of the KeySelector to the queryable.OrderBy method so that I do not have to compare and invoke the method by Type? In an ideal world I would be able to write the following code.

```cs
queryable = queryable.OrderBy(keySelector);
```

But that results in

> The type arguments for method `Queryable.OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.